# Windows 10 thinks I am obligated to use the the Indian version of the German keyboard layout

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, powershell, keyboard-layout

It turns out, I cannot remove this keyboard layout (on regedit, its code is d0010407. Deleting it won't have any effect since it keeps coming back after restart. Another suspected side effect is that, it seems to mess up with the actual keyboard itself. Sometimes, if I click on a certain key on an on-screen keyboard it gives me a different key.
For example, pressing on ü gives me ß, ö gives ü and ä gives ö
How do I get rid of this? I tried powershell commands from a youtube tutorial but the command to remove it keeps returning "false" instead of "true":

*

```
$LangList = Get-WinUserLanguageList*

*$MarkedLang = $LangList | where LanguageTag -eq de-IN*

*$LangList.Remove($MarkedLang)*

*Set-WinUserLanguageList $LangList –Force*
```

After the third command, it returns "false" where it should have returned "true"

This is the result of Get-Culture and GetUICulture commands on PowerShell:

```
**Get-Culture | fl ***


Parent                         : en

LCID                           : 2057

KeyboardLayoutId               : 2057

Name                           : en-GB

IetfLanguageTag                : en-GB

DisplayName                    : English (United Kingdom)

NativeName                     : English (United Kingdom)

EnglishName                    : English (United Kingdom)

TwoLetterISOLanguageName       : en

ThreeLetterISOLanguageName     : eng

ThreeLetterWindowsLanguageName : ENG

CompareInfo                    : CompareInfo - en-GB

TextInfo                       : TextInfo - en-GB

IsNeutralCulture               : False

CultureTypes                   : SpecificCultures, InstalledWin32Cultures,
 FrameworkCultures
NumberFormat                   : System.Globalization.NumberFormatInfo

DateTimeFormat                 : System.Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo

Calendar                       : System.Globalization.GregorianCalendar

OptionalCalendars              : {System.Globalization.GregorianCalendar, System.Globalization.GregorianCalendar}

UseUserOverride                : True

IsReadOnly                     : False







**Get-UICulture | fl ***


Parent                         : en

LCID                           : 2057

KeyboardLayoutId               : 2057

Name                           : en-GB

IetfLanguageTag                : en-GB

DisplayName                    : English (United Kingdom)

NativeName                     : English (United Kingdom)

EnglishName                    : English (United Kingdom)

TwoLetterISOLanguageName       : en

ThreeLetterISOLanguageName     : eng

ThreeLetterWindowsLanguageName : ENG

CompareInfo                    : CompareInfo - en-GB

TextInfo                       : TextInfo - en-GB

IsNeutralCulture               : False

CultureTypes                   : SpecificCultures, InstalledWin32Cultures,
 FrameworkCultures
NumberFormat                   : System.Globalization.NumberFormatInfo

DateTimeFormat                 : System.Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo

Calendar                       : System.Globalization.GregorianCalendar

OptionalCalendars              : {System.Globalization.GregorianCalendar, System.Globalization.GregorianCalendar}

UseUserOverride                : True

IsReadOnly                     : False
```

This is what I got after the "gwmi win32_quickfixengineering | sort installedon -des" command:

```
Source        Description      HotFixID      InstalledBy          InstalledOn              
------        -----------      --------      -----------          -----------              
DESKTOP-0L... Security Update  KB4338832     NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM  11/07/2018 00:00:00      
DESKTOP-0L... Security Update  KB4338819     NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM  11/07/2018 00:00:00      
DESKTOP-0L... Update           KB4343669     NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM  10/07/2018 00:00:00      
DESKTOP-0L... Security Update  KB4287903     NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM  08/06/2018 00:00:00
```

Comment: check the output of powershell's "Get-Culture | fl *"  and "Get-UICulture | fl *" where Get-Culture is the current culture on the system and the Get-UICulture is the current user interface (UI) culture settings for Windows

Comment: Thanks for the input, I tried them both Get-Culture | fl * and Get-UICulture | fl * but they returned absolutely nothing. Is it even a recognized command?

Comment: what version of PS

Comment: My bad, I used Powershell ISE instead of the one marked as "Desktop app" and it returned results.

Comment: I added them to my original question

Comment: which keyboards are available      reg query "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Keyboard Layout\Preload"

Comment: 5 of them: 00000809, 0000042c, 00000419, 00000417, and the infamous d0010407 (which is invisible and cannot be taken out from the language settings)

Comment: are you remoting?

Comment: Not at all, this is just a personal computer of mine. I was able to get rid of this problem couple months ago but Windows seems determined to add it back after updates, for good this time. Although I have no idea why

Comment: delete all but English 00000809 and see if this helps, as it may be a parent or daughter of one of the others.  0000042c Azeri Latin, 00000419 Russian, 00000417 German.

Comment: Well, surprisingly the parasitic key (d0010407) was not even there but it still showed up in my list of languages.  I deleted all but English and all languages still remain in my list even though the registry shows just 00000809. Is thereba way to reset this back to normal?

Comment: try $i = New-WinUserLanguageList en-Gb;
Set-WinUserLanguageList $i

Comment: Should I try this on powershell?

Comment: yes this is a powershell command.

Comment: Well, it just asked me whether I wanted to "continue with that operation" and upon clicking yes nothing absolutely has happened.

Comment: Update, after a restart, my language bar disappeared since there were only 1 language - English left anyway. I started adding all the other languages back and upon adding German that wretched German-Indian keyboard found its way again?
Why would windows force me to do this?

Comment: Update, I don't know how, but somehow I just noticed that it is gone, whether it was the powershell commands, or windows fixing them, I have no idea but the problem seems to be fixed finally.

Comment: I think probably windows bug was fixed

Comment: Probably, although this happened before, where the Indian keyboard disappeared and came right back in a month or so later.

Comment: And, it came back again :D

Comment: Try  "gwmi win32_quickfixengineering | sort installedon -desc" to find which updates have been applied recently  so you could roll back pre kb update maybe you can find which specific update causes it.

Comment: @Antony, Thanks for this suggestion, but I still have no idea why there is no a directly or file where the keyboard settings are actually stored so I can actually go in there and change it. This is really stupid and I really doubt something like this happens by accident. But I can't figure out why windows forces me to use the dysfunctional indian keyboard

Comment: I added the results of that command into my main question, but I don't see how this is useful. Is it really reasonable to roll back an entire update because of one thing?

Comment: Consider showing us `$LangList | ft -Property LanguageTag, InputMethodTipS`. Check the output thoroughly: then you can see, that `$MarkedLang = $LangList | where LanguageTag -eq de-IN` results to `$null` as `de-IN` is not a valid LanguageTag…